# Cannot Fill NaN with zeros in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have the following problem: 
I am reading a csv file with missing values by using

`pd.read_csv(f_name, sep=sep, header=hdr, parse_dates=True, index_col=date_col, quotechar=quote)`

The dataframe I get has 'nan's in it (I was expecting 'NaN's with the Upper cases).
Now if I try to replace those nan's with zerosby using

```
df.fillna(0)
```

my df doesn't change (I still see nan's in it)
My guess is that fillna is not working because I have nan (lowercase) instead of NaN (uppercase). Am I correct?
If yes, do you have an idea why pd.read.csv returns a dataframe with lowercase nan's?
I am using Python 2.7.6 (Anaconda bundle)

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: pls post ``df.head()`` and ``df.info()``

Answer (score 14):

`df.fillna(0)` returns a new dataframe; it does not alter `df`.

So instead use:

```
df = df.fillna(0)           # assigns df to a new dataframe
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, helps a lot. Clearly should read the document more carefully.

Comment: could also use df.fillna(0, inplace = True)