# Compare tables to create presence/absence matrix filling empty without decimals

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Command line:

files can be found at git-hub.

File1:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felipelira/files_to_test/master/file1.txt

File2:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felipelira/files_to_test/master/file2.txt

Command line:
    python teste2.py file1.txt file2.txt test

When converting a tabular file in a presence/absence matrix I missed some data in the end. The genomes without a match with an accession were not plot.

My previous result was something like this (according the script and example at the post [Convert tables to presence/absence matrix python - Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49035358/5775504)):

```
genome  accession1  accession2  accession3  accession4  accession5
genome1           1           1           1           0           0
genome2           1           0           0           1           1
```

But I need the other genomes in my forward analysis.
I tried to arrange this moving the block that defines df2 before the df1:

```
asmbly_dict = sys.argv[1]
blast_result = sys.argv[2]
outName = sys.argv[3] + '.txt'

with open(blast_result, 'r') as file2:
    col_genes = ['gene', 'accession']
    df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, sep='\t', header=None, names=col_genes)
    print df2

with open(asmbly_dict, 'r') as file1:
    col_asmbly = ['gene', 'genome']
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, sep='\t', header=None, names=col_asmbly)
    df1['accession'] = df1['gene'].map(df2.set_index('gene')['accession'])
    #print df1
    g = df1.groupby('genome')['accession'].apply(list).reset_index()
    testdf = g.join(pd.get_dummies(g['accession'].apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)).drop('accession', 1)
    #print testdf.to_string(index=False)
    testdf.to_csv(outName, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
```

Print of df2:

```
    gene   accession
0  gene1  accession1
1  gene2  accession2
2  gene3  accession3
3  gene4  accession1
4  gene5  accession4
5  gene6  accession5
```

Print of df1:

```
    gene   genome   accession
0  gene1  genome1  accession1
1  gene2  genome1  accession2
2  gene3  genome1  accession3
3  gene4  genome2  accession1
4  gene5  genome2  accession4
5  gene6  genome2  accession5
6  gene7  genome3         NaN
7  gene8  genome3         NaN
8  gene9  genome4         NaN
```

Print of testdf:

```
genome  accession1  accession2  accession3  accession4  accession5
genome1         1.0         1.0         1.0         0.0         0.0
genome2         1.0         0.0         0.0         1.0         1.0
genome3         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
genome4         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

And the .csv file:

```
genome  accession1  accession2  accession3  accession4  accession5
genome1         1.0         1.0         1.0         0.0         0.0
genome2         1.0         0.0         0.0         1.0         1.0
genome3
genome4
```

The problems are:

How to plot no decimals after numbers (1.0 -> 1) and how can I fill the empty values with zeros to print and write the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Fill NaN with zeros in a Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801507/cannot-fill-nan-with-zeros-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want use your original solution add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with cast to `int`:

```
testdf = g.join(pd.get_dummies(g['accession'].apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)).drop('accession', 1)

testdf = testdf.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

But better solution is use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) and then set `max` per index and per columns (in sample not necessary, in real data maybe):

```
df1['accession'] = df1['gene'].map(df2.set_index('gene')['accession'])

df1 = pd.get_dummies(df1.set_index('genome')['accession']).max(level=0).max(level=0, axis=1)
```

Or use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html), [`clip_upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip_upper.html) and add missing categories by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df1 = (pd.crosstab(df1['genome'], df1['accession'])
        .clip_upper(1)
        .reindex(df1['genome'].unique(), fill_value=0))
```

Or:

```
df1 = (df1.groupby(['genome', 'accession'])
         .size()
         .clip_upper(1)
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reindex(df1['genome'].unique(), fill_value=0))
```

---

```
print (df1)
         accession1  accession2  accession3  accession4  accession5
genome                                                             
genome1           1           1           1           0           0
genome2           1           0           0           1           1
genome3           0           0           0           0           0
genome4           0           0           0           0           0
```

and last for write to file:

```
df1.to_csv(outName, sep='\t')
```